# Multiple $_POST variable?

Tags: php, mysql

What am I doing wrong here?

```
// INSERT: if we have a name to add...
if($_POST['email'] &  $_POST['job_id'] ) {
   // little bit of cleaning...
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $job_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['job_id']);
   // insert new name into table
   $sql = "INSERT INTO job_applications (id, email, job_id) VALUES ('','$email,'$job_id')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
} // end if
```

I am using '&' but with no luck, is there a certain syntax to include on the variable? Simply want to "if($_POST[])" more then one value at a time?

Comment: You want to know if both those values are non-empty?  `&` is the bitwise AND operator, `&&` is the _logical_ `AND`.

Comment: Don't do this. `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);` Use binded parameters and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO job_applications (id, email, job_id) VALUES ('','$email,'$job_id')";
```

For

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO job_applications (id, email, job_id) VALUES ('', '$email','$job_id')";
```

There's a fault quote.

And, its `&&` and not `&`

`&&` = AND

`||` = OR

And update yourself by using PDO, it's more secure and **cool**.

As @S.Visser said, PDO has some cool stuffs, like: prepared statements, placeholder and it's a lil more secure against SQL Injection.

It's not hard to use:

```
// Connect to MySQL Server
$user = "test";
$pass = "test";
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
// Prepare some statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE `email` = :email");
```

Bind some param, params are commonly represented with `:` before param name. Like: 
`:email`, `:name`, `:pass`, `:user`, etc...
[`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) also holds an third argument, it's value type.
Value type is represented with PDO constants that can be found here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php
These constants looks like `PDO::PARAM_*`
[`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) also do the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) job, and quote the value when needed.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':email', 'email@example.com');
// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
// Fetch the result
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Show result array with print_r
print_r($result);
```

Well, that's all, sorry about english, i'm brazilian :P

Comment: When you want to spread your love for PDO please give a reason and explain it.

Comment: Thank you and I will be looking into PDO.

Comment: @Nicos i added a simple PDO tutorial within my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are using & instead of &&. **&&** is the logical AND, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php,
**&** is a bitwise operation, which is not what you are looking for here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&&` instead of just `&`. That makes sure both conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Past Code in if statement.**

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['job_id'])) {
```

Comment: and also use PDO Class for Database connectivity. never use mysql_real_escape_string for sql injection

Comment: PDO is such an hype here on Stackoverflow. more then 50% I read this kind of comments. When you want to spread your love for PDO please give a reason then, not just say: `use PDO`

Comment: Many PHP programmers learned how to access databases by using either the MySQL or MySQLi extensions. As of PHP 5.1, there’s a better way. PHP Data Objects (PDO) provide methods for prepared statements and working with objects that will make you far more productive!

Comment: @bolanhost an informative link on PDO class would be greatly appreciated, what would be the PDO class opposed to mysql_real_escape_string? My DB connection  should be changed to: 

$pdo = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password');

Thanks for the infromation, I don't know where I would be without StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

> TS: Simply want to "if($_POST[])" more then one value at a time?

There is a way to loop trough you $_POST[''] because its a array. But you need to be careful with it and check every user input!

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $post) {
  if(empty($post) {
   echo $key ." is empty";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the logical operator ( `&&` vs `&` ), you would do better to use:

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['job_id']) )
```

otherwise your server could be producing a warning and logging it which will be a performance hit.

Comment: Actually you can do `isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['job_id'])` to achieve the same thing. See [here](http://php.net/isset). It is easier to read, especially when checking for 3 or more values.

Comment: @vascowhite Use "isset" instead of &&?

Comment: @Nicos He's using isset in the answer anyway, I'm just suggesting a cleaner way of using it.

Comment: @vascowhite thank you, lots of help here. Much appreciated.